# STI and PUNDIT - unable to find policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti, pundit

I have three `models`:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
class Diary < Post
class FuturePlans < Post
```

I have also included the pundit in `posts_controller.rb`:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
 include Pundit
```

And I have a `post_policy.rb`:

```
class BlogPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

class Scope < Scope
 def resolve
  return scope.all
 end
end
```

I seeded some diaries and futureplans with bankseed, included pundit in all the actions inside the controller, and I get the following error:

```
unable to find policy "DiaryPolicy" for "#<Diary id:...
```

Should I make separate policies for Diary and FuturePlans? How do I make them inherit pundit as well? When I disable pundit it all works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created DiaryPolicy and FuturePlansPolicy and it works again.

Comment: Worth mentioning those two classes you have derived from `PostPolicy`.